# На каком полигоне расположена метка?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть 3 полигона, созданные с помощью:

```
var pol1 = new ymaps.Polygon(pol_coords);

var pol2 = new ymaps.Polygon(pol_coords2);

var pol3 = new ymaps.Polygon(pol_coords3);
```

Есть форма над картой с input полем, в которой указывается адрес, после чего на карте создаётся метка в точке полученных координат.

Если вызывать событие клик, то всё прекрасно работает, зону я могу передавать самостоятельно.

```
pol1.events.add('click', function (e) {check_zone(e,'zone1'); });

pol2.events.add('click', function (e) {check_zone(e,'zone2'); });
```

Не могу понять как узнать на каком именно полигоне в данный момент расположена метка (без клика по полигону), а перед её созданием

Можно ли получить название перемененной(объекта) во время создания метки? В зависимости от зоны, будет выводится разный текст.

```
if(zone=='pol1'){

    text='Первый текст';

}else if(zone=='pol2'){

    text='Второй текст';

}
```

Знаю, что можно сверять координаты метки с координатами в массиве, но у меня как-то не вышло. Функция contains отказывается работать с текущими функциями создания карты. Есть другие варианты?

Comment: А смотрели [пример в песочнице](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones?from=SO)?

Comment: Смотрел, но придётся весь скрипт переделывать, а мне нужно лишь узнать принадлежат ли координаты метки одному из полигонов.
<pre><code>
myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
//Получаем координаты метки (Получены)
//Как-то узнаём принадлежность координат метки к полигону
//pol_coords и pol_coords2 содержат массив координат
//В зависимости от зоны переменная text будет добавлять разный текст
add_text(text);
     
});
</pre></code>

Comment: В API есть методы geoQueryResult, которые позволяют, например, найти точки внутри полигона: [вот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemarks_in_circle?from=SO)